# angularjs while Posting multpart data its getting converted to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

while sending POST request with multipart data with image and other fields in angularjs , boolean values getting converted to string how to resolve it.

```
var fd=new FormData();
 fd.append('name',$scope.spname);
 fd.append('profile_picture',$scope.cmpylogo);
 fd.append('new_picture',false);
 $http({method:'POST',
   url:BaseUrl.url+'/speaker/',
   data:fd,
   transformRequest: angular.identity,
   headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
 }).then(function success(response){
    console.log(response.data);
 });
```

Comment: Try adding `contentType = 'multipart/form-data` below `url` line in the code.

Comment: When i try with multipart/form-data i'm getting error as `MultiPartParserError: Invalid boundary in multipart: None "`